# Preventing Google from indexing ".com" instead of ".com/fr" or ".com/en"

Tags: google, google-search-console, multilingual, search-results

I followed the recommendation of Google concerning multilingual website, I have:

- `www.example.com/fr` in french
- `www.example.com/en` in english
- `www.example.com` automatically redirects (header) either to  `www.example.com/fr` or `www.example.com/en`.

In my *sitemap.xml*, I have not mentionned `www.example.com` but instead the two subdirectories, still following Google on sitemap policy:

```
<url>
  <loc>http://www.example.com/fr/</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.example.com/en/"/>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="http://www.example.com/fr/"/>
  <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
 <priority>1.00</priority>
</url>
<url>
  <loc>http://www.example.com/en/</loc>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="fr" href="http://www.example.com/fr/"/>
  <xhtml:link rel="alternate" hreflang="en" href="http://www.example.com/en/"/>
  <changefreq>daily</changefreq>
  <priority>1.00</priority>
</url>
```

Problem is that in Google, the main results is `www.example.com`.
For many websites, Google displays for the first results `.com/fr` or `.com/en` depending our location but not juste `.com`.

I was thinking of using Webmaster Tools and try remove `www.example.com` but I'm not sure since `www.example.com` is not really a sitelink and I'm afraid it will juste remove my site from Google. Do I miss something? Or maybe I should just wait?

Comment: How are you determining which language to redirect towards?  Is it based on geographic IP address or `Accept-Language` header?   How is Googlebot treated?  It almost always crawls from the US and it doesn't send a `Accept-Language` header.

Comment: Did you used to have on of the languages hosted in the root folder?  If so, how long ago was that?

Comment: Very good points : If the user doesn't browse .ocm/fr or .com/en but just .com, I redirect using the ip adress and making a call to an online api. Once I get the answer, I redirect to /fr (if france) or /en else.
Now, 2 months ago, I had only one url : ".com" and language of the this page was also found using ip to set a session variable. At this time, my website was indexed in english (i guess because googlebot crawl from us). But now (and for 2 months now), i have different urls for the two languages.

Answer (score 3):

You need to include the "/" URL in your Sitemap file and specify it as the [hreflang](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077) "[x-default](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.ch/2013/04/x-default-hreflang-for-international-pages.html)". That way, Google will know that this is a part of your set of pages, and will be able to handle it appropriately. Note that hreflang is a signal, and not a directive for Google, so it might be that the "/" URL still occasionally shows up.

Answer (score 2):

Your general setup sounds fine.   A few things to check:

- When you do your geo-IP redirects, ensure that they are the "301 permanent" variety.  If you are using 302 temporary redirects, Google will be hesitant to change the URLs
- Test Googlebot specifically.

I tend to use a command line program like `curl` to test these items.  Make sure the information you get back looks similar to the following:

```
curl --head --user-agent 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Googlebot/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)' http://example.com/
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: http://example.com/en/
```

If you need to make any additional changes, it may take Googlebot a week to realize the home page has moved and a month or more to get to all the pages on the site.

Comment: Ok. For now, it's redirected using a header location request, so it's 302 by default. I can set it to be 301.
What do you mean by "test googlebot specifically" ? You mean, in my php code, to detect if it's googlebot and do specific actions in that case, or is the action in robots.txt ?

Comment: Use a Googlebot user agent when contacting the server.  That is why I use the `--user-agent` flag with `curl`.

Comment: Curl is sending me 406 answer : "LiteSpeed technology is not responsible for administration and contents of this web site!"

Comment: 406 is a very unusual response code.  It would be worth getting to the bottom of what is generating it and why.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14251851/what-is-406-not-acceptable-response-in-http

Comment: Actually, "curl --head http://example.com/" gives 406 code. your request, gives : 
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: (compatible;
curl: (6) Could not resolve host: Googlebot
curl: (1) Protocol +http not supported or disabled in libcurl
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Tue, 21 Jan 2014 16:28:12 GMT
Server: LiteSpeed
Connection: close
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.23
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=6d45be72d9847aaa8112d2d51efcec5c; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-che
Pragma: no-cache
Location: /fr/
Content-Type: text/html

Comment: You must include the `http://` on the URL when using curl. (And you will want to replace "example.com" with your own web site.)

Comment: Yes, don't worry, i replace with my own ;) Ok, nice it's working. And with your request, as you can see, I have a 301 code + Location /fr/. Let's wait and see now. thanks a lot